# Symfony 2 form posting data but not inserting it

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have a form built in Symfony 2.8 and I have been stumped for a few days trying to work out why a field will not populate.

So I have a form that is inserting a product for an order and the fields are all posting but the insert query is not picking up the data. It thinks the field is null.

Any suggestions?

[image: Profiler Screenshot]

[image: Symfony Error Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please show us your controller action?

Comment: You `products` is a collection, make sure to double check the persistence options on your database models. We sometimes had situations where simply relying on the form validation / persisting didn't work with collections.

Answer (score 1):

First check your inserted data is valid for price field or change your price field nullable true.

If it's not helping you then describe your code descriptively.